# Search unanswered in multiple tags

Tags: bug, tags, search, unanswered-questions

I'd like to search unanswered questions that have multiple specific tags.

Example: I want to find unanswered questions that are tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps), just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+google-maps). But when I now click <kbd>unanswered</kbd>, I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android+google-maps) page where my specified tags are ignored.

Is this weird behavior a bug or is it supposed to be like this (for whatever weird reason)?

Comment: Just came to Meta three years later after observing this same issue. I see the advanced search answer below, but this still felt like unexpected behavior (OR vs. AND for multiple tags). I'm sure I'm not the only one who assumed this is a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the advanced search functionality:

[`[android] and [google-maps] answers:0 closed:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+and+%5Bgoogle-maps%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)

Which gives you questions:

- tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps)
- zero answers
- not closed

Comment: Thanks, but is my original problem a bug or a wired "feature"?

Comment: @fyfyoneGoogle this is already possible in the new nav https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android%20google-maps?filter=need-answers&mode=all (which behaves the same way as unanswered) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android%20google-maps?filter=no-answer&mode=all (which behaves the same way as rene search)

Comment: It does feel like a bug, or at least an inconsistent design.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+google-maps
- Works as expected (the two tags are ANDed)

http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android+google-maps
- Doesn't work as expected (the two tags are ORed)

Solution? Explicitly AND the tags:

http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android+and+google-maps