# Search by multiple tags fails to behave in the unanswered tab

Tags: bug

On Stack Overflow I can search questions that have all of the specified tags by entering, in the search area:

```
[tag1][tag2]
```

Which leads to a URL like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka+java
```

Note that in that page the tab selected by default is "active".

If I now navigate among the tabs, for example the "vote" one, I get

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka+java?sort=votes&pageSize=50
```

And all the displayed questions have both tags, as expected. This behavior is shared by all tags, but the "unanswered" one. Clicking on it yield the URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/akka+java
```

But the questions displayed here are only having the latter of the specified tags, not both.

This has been reported already for example [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323524/search-unanswered-in-multiple-tags), but even if it's possible to achieve the result in the way specified there, which BTW is VERY complicated, the behavior in both the clicking on tabs and URL parsing for unanswered feels wrong. Perhaps we should change the link on clicking the unanswered tab to repoint to the complicated version?

Comment: quick workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/akka+and+java - however, I agree  that this is entirely bizarre - taking a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, the "unanswered" tab functioned as "or", not "and" (by default). I agree that this is very confusing, and should be improved. As a secondary bug, note that the tag-map also works incorrectly as a result - if I search for [`xslt`](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/xslt), the tag-map shows the intersection with other tags:

[image]

This *suggests* that if I click on `java` I'm going to filter down to the 361 questions, but instead I get [`xslt+java`](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/xslt+java) for 308k+ questions, because it is doing an "or".

My view is that we should challenge the existing state that `/unanswered` defaults to "or". I will try to check the origins, but I *wonder* whether this relates to the [`tab=mytags`](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags) feature, but *if* that  is the origin, that can be trivially fixed by having the expansion include the implied "or".

The  alternative fix would be for the  tab-links (including "unanswered") to include explicit combiners (using whatever the implied one is for that page), so that when you navigate away you *retain* the same combiner - and for the tag map to *always* append "and {foo}" rather than just "{foo}". Standardising on a single default  behaviour would be simpler, cleaner and more intuitive IMO, though.

Comment: I'll assign the correct answer to this one, and move it if something better comes along as answer (possibly someone actually having found the source?)

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia oh, I've absolutely found the cause - I've even written up notes on which lines need changing; I want to discuss the proposed changes with some folks, though, as it will change the long-established behavior of that page. I want to run it past  folks, is all. Unfortunately, most folks are at a company meetup this week.

Comment: ok sorry, I misunderstood the line :)