# Is multi tag search broken?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

When searching for example for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+oop), I get multiple results that do not have both tags, but just one of them:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+oop returns:
[image: search results for https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+oop]

And:

[image: results count]

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ruby+postgres) [searches](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/swift+testing) with similiar results.

But for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c+ios), seems to work.

Has the behavior for multi tag search changed, or is it broken? (Or is it me that didn't understand how the feature works? :P )

Comment: Yeah, search is broken.  You can even get it to serve you up deleted questions.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323524/search-unanswered-in-multiple-tags

Comment: note that furthermore it may switch you from relevant to newest or the opposite, don't remember which way.

Comment: related: [Better support for search by both intersection and union of multiple tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231693/137096)

Comment: Search was working fine for me until about Feb 16 or 17, 2020; then it broke.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's some history here around whether pages specifying multiple tags should work as *unions* or *intersections* (by default). It isn't consistent, and there are some glitches with changing tabs, and with the tag-cloud that appends tags to the url. It isn't perfect, I'll be honest.

However, if you're *explicit*, it'll always work as you expect:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+and+oop
```

vs

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+or+oop
```

The same applies to the other pages, like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+and+oop
```

vs

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+oop
```

Comment: Yup. If I use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+and+oop, it'll redirect me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php, but with http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+and+oop it appears to work.

Comment: Again, with "questions", it just [redirects](http://i.imgur.com/o34RgPl.png) me. :P

Comment: @yivi you shouldn't be redirected unless you are anonymous (we block multi-tag searches) - can you confirm that you're logged in and are being redirected?

Comment: @yivi I should also note that our "anonymous single tag only redirect" thing relates to a bot attack *years* ago, on a completely different tag-engine implementation; I'll see whether we might want to reverse that...

Comment: Sorry, I was purposely trying as anoymous to verify there was no nothing in my session that was influencing the results. :)

Comment: As an authenticated user, it seems to work as you say.

Comment: @yivi in about 3 minutes, anonymous users will be able to use 3 tags at a time (easily configurable if we want to change the number)

Comment: Wondrous. Not that I browse SO anonymously so often, but still, nice to feel that you guys are paying attention. :)

Comment: @MarcGravell What's the reasoning behind blocking anonymous users from multi-tag searches?

Comment: @TylerH at the time we added that, we were under sustained hammering from badly behaved crawlers; multi-tag was very rarely used by "real" anons, and was disproportionately expensive. Was causing pain. We've completely rewritten the code underneath all that now, so happy to see how it behaves as we loosen it

Comment: I see that you applied the "status-bydesign" tag. Is it really "by design" that the tag search has glitches that causes it to defy expectations? As I commented on another answer, the exact same search query being interpreted differently on different tabs is, as far as I'm concerned, a bug, either in the code or in the UI. I don't think this should be by design. It may be that you're afraid to touch this code and break something else, or it may just not be high priority to fix, but this certainly doesn't seem like something that should be "by design" to me.

Comment: @CodyGray it is "by design" in at least as much as I've raised this topic in our internal chat a few months ago, discussed it at length with various teams, and we concluded that we wish to leave it "as is" at the current time. It is an active, not passive, position.

Comment: Any insight that you can provide on the rationale for that decision? Your answer doesn't give much of a clue. I've been confused by this behavior several times, so while I welcome the workaround you've suggested, the position being taken seems (at least from the outside looking in) illogical.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Marc's suggestion, you can get the search to show questions with both [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop) by toggling the switch between "any" and "all" on the right edge of the search bar:

[image]

However, you may have to wait a bit to use those buttons; for some reason, they only show up *after* a new question has been posted, and you see the "1 new question" alert bar at the top of the list.

If you can't see it and don't want to wait, the URL is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php%20oop?filter=need-answers&mode=all

Comment: Only if you're using the "new navigation" stuff, which as far as I can tell, is still in beta. (Not promising, btw, to have a beta last this long, Gmail notwithstanding.)

Comment: @CodyGray yeah, I am a bit surprised to learn that not everyone is on that navigation view by now... I thought they were.

Answer (score 2):

If you go through the **unanswered** tab,  it works as a **`or`** (`tag1 || tag2`). This is the way you make your research.

Note you can see it on the URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+oop
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, it displays only `tag1 && tag2` questions if you select the **questions** tab.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+oop
                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

[image]

---

It could be a bug, but working with URL seems to returns the expected results.

Comment: Now I see that the actual link includes `unanswered` as part of the URL, but that that part is ignored in tab selection... Besides that, even changing tabs I  see that the [results](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/swift+testing?tab=noanswers) are filtered with `||`, not with `&&`. I don't know if its a bug or a feature unless I know what would be the **intended** behavior.

Comment: @yivi Read again my answer please. The difference is in the URL: `unanswered` is `||`. `questions` is `&&`.

Comment: The exact same search query being interpreted differently on different tabs is definitely a bug.

Comment: I can't replicate your results, sorry. But even if behaved that way, it would be faulty to me. I mostly agree with @cody-gray: same query should return the same results, unless documented somewhere than it wont. But the more I play with the search interface and its tabs, the more inconsistent I find it. But a week or two ago, it seemed to me that the multi-tag filter was working...

Comment: @yivi `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+oop` works, `http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+oop`does not works.

Comment: Not for me. When I try the first one, it redirects me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php

Comment: @yivi The first URL returns the correct results for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfciG.png

Comment: Not for me. It redirects me. Tried FF, FF for developers, and chrome. Private sessions with empty cookies. Will redirect me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php

Comment: And again, it would still be a bug for me if that was the answer.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/o34RgPl.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzONY.png