# Has the behaviour of combined tags search changed?

Tags: bug, tags, search

*This is not a dup of [Is multi tag search broken?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342814/is-multi-tag-search-broken) from 3 years ago!*  This is a fresh recurrence of that problem.

I have a weird situation since this morning.

I watch questions containing both [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) **and** [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) tags with below link. (on search bar it is `[datetime] [c#]`)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime+c%23?sort=newest

Since this morning, I saw some questions tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), some questions tagged with only [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) (not contains [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime)), even some questions with tagged only [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) (not contains [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)). Even when I wrote this question, I saw 2 questions that *doesn't* include [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) tag. When I refresh the page, the 2 question that I mark below gone by the way.

Was there any change have been made for this search that I'm not aware of? Did I miss something?

[image]

Comment: Should this question really be closed as a duplicate of [Is multi tag search broken?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342814/4642212)? That’s from three years ago, but apparently _new_ problems have arisen, leading to new questions like [Recent fix broke AND-OR queries; cf “nn questions with new activity”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394046/4642212).

Comment: @user4642212 I'm little bit confused about closing or not at first, honestly. There are _still_ some problems on "Search". Even we know that, so, should we close all questions about "search not working properly" as a duplicate? Even they _still_ appears? On my personal view, this situation affected me really bad. I stopped to monitor questions because even I filter with `[datetime] and [c#]` (in url: `c%23+and+datetime`) some questions with tagged `python`, questions contains only `c#` or questions contains only `datetime` tag(s) drop that page and this makes the page unmanageable.

Comment: @SonerGönül - I see "close as dup" to be a "consolidation" of multiple items, thereby helping focus effort into one item.  But only if the items are the "same".  I'll vote to reopen yours.  After that, your item can be a dup of my _current_ bug report or vice versa.

Comment: @user4642212 - I agree with you.  Soner's issue is the same as mine ("Recent fix..."), _not_ the 3-year-old item.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [“X questions with new activity” showing incorrect information in windows with multiple tag filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343767/344280) on MSE.  Since the functionality was explicitly documented to work in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128126/344280) by a stack exchange employee, it's a regression.