# Newest activity for 2 or more tags shows questions with new activity when the just the last tag does

Tags: bug, search, tag-search

**Note** This is **NOT** a duplicate of [Has the behaviour of combined tags search changed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393969) - the criteria for initial load of the page is all tags must be present, the criteria for new activity is the *last* tag being present. They should be consistent, and multi-tag search is useless if only the last one matters.

*Before* you flag to close this as a duplicate: **I AM NOT ASKING HOW COMBINED TAG SEARCH WORKS!**

The **BUG** is that the initial search brings back a *different* set to the background *new activity* check.

Those should be consistent, **WHATEVER AND|OR|LAST-TAG-WINS RULES THEY FOLLOW**

---

You can select multiple tags to look for questions on. For instance here is the newest activity for questions tagged with *both* `[lit-element]` `[javascript]`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lit-element%2bjavascript?tab=Newest

Note that the initial load joins the tags with an `AND` - all tags must be present for a question to be in the initial results.

However, background checks tell you when there is new activity using *different* logic:

[image: screenshot showing new activity]

This will show the `x question with new activity` header for **just** the `[javascript]` tag. If I open this at the same time:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript

The new activity counts will be identical.

It appears to depend on the last tag - flipping the tags around swaps which tag is checked, so:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%2blit-element?tab=Newest

Matches:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lit-element?tab=Newest

If searching for multiple tags the `Newest` tab should only show new activity on questions tagged with *all* the tags.

This question is **not** about whether this should be `AND` or `OR` (or event last tag listed wins) logic. The bug is that the logic for checking for new questions is *different* from that for the initial load, and if you refresh the page the results will be different to if you click the link to load in the new questions.

Whatever logic is intended is not the problem, it should be the **same** between reload and fetching new questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has the behaviour of combined tags search changed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393969/has-the-behaviour-of-combined-tags-search-changed)

Comment: @yivi no. The page loads with questions tagged with both, but "new activity" is shown just for the _last_ tag. Either the new activity should also be both, or the initial load should return all questions with the last tag.

Comment: It seems to work as expected for me when using `or`. eg [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+or+node.js+or+reactjs?sort=newest&pageSize=50), I see some new activity questions that are not tagged with JavaScript

Comment: Same for when you want to exclude a tag. Thanks for reporting this it has been annoying me for quite some time.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, `or` might be _as expected_, but tags separated by spaces and nothing else should default to `and` anyway - nobody wants to cast the net wider on SO. It's also beside the point: I'm **not** saying I don't understand how tag behaviour works, I'm saying the behaviour is _different between initial load and background checks for updates_.