# Filter question by newest bounty gives me questions without bounty as well

Tags: bug, filtering

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=Newest&filters=Bounty

Despite the filter `Bounty` I get questions without it.

1. To reproduce the bug go to
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=Newest&filters=Bounty
2. Wait till new questions are asked
3. Click on [image]

The unfiltered questions will then appear

> [image: bug image]

Comment: When you create a bug report, then it is always useful to add all important information. That this issue only happens after opening the page and loading new questions via "x questions with new activity" notification is missing here.

Comment: I'll edit my post.

Comment: You might also want to read the excerpt for the tag [meta-tag:bug-reports] ...

Comment: I'm going to guess that the answer is "caching"

Comment: I would bet this is strongly related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407628/1426539) and similar previous reports.

Comment: @DavidW it often is but in this case I blame over active websockets: *Here, you really want to show this message. Show it! Just ignore what the user filtered on. Push it!*