# Filter by Bounty queues up regular questions as well

Tags: discussion, questions, filtering

In SO's `Bountied` question tab, the default values are selected or checked:

- Filter by —> Has bounty

  Sorted by —> Bounty ending soon

  Tagged with —> *no values* (however, python tagged in this example)

Changing the default 'sorted by' to 'newest' (for example) eventually picks up non-bountied questions as well (see image). I tested this by waiting 1-2 minutes to see if some questions began to appear/refresh. And the same thing for the situation were the default values where not changed, but it appeared that no non-bountied questions showed up on the page (based on the same amount of time).

Should this be the case? I would think that simply changing 'Sorted by' in this scenario would not queue up the non-bountied questions as well.

[image]

Comment: I expect this to be status-bydesign. The "new activity" feature works by subscribing to websocket messages for a tag. The websocket subscription is rather limited and it certainly doesn't have the knowledge of what filters are applied. In this case it simply started listening for activity on the python tag, and when it receives a message it updates the banner, no matter what extra filters you applied.

Comment: Similar / related:  [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393969/has-the-behaviour-of-combined-tags-search-changed)

Comment: @rene Couldn't some Javascript code then suppress the working of the "new activity" feature if after filtering nothing new remains. It probably would to convey more information.

Comment: What about changing the wording to "Up to X questions with new activity, reload to find out."?

Comment: @Trilarion I'm sure there is an easy fix to make the behavior less surprising. We only need to find that one dev that has 6 to 8 time-units available to implement it ...

Comment: I keep noticing this for my custom filters and it's pretty annoying. I hope this is not by design, but rather just an oversight.

Comment: @rene Always these devs that are so rare. A real bottleneck they are and that despite more than a decade of SO.