# Site searches for multiple tags appear to update with new questions for any tag

Tags: bug, search, live-refresh

I had open a search for `[multiple-return-values] [python]`, showing me a small collection of questions which have both tags.

After a while, the site started adding new [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) questions to the search results (hidden under the 'update' button), even though these new questions had nothing to do with [multiple-return-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-return-values) and were not tagged as such. Presumably, it would add results the other way around, as well.

I think this is a bug. If the initial query only found existing questions with both tags, then it should only add newly-asked questions that match both tags - not either tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has the behaviour of combined tags search changed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393969/has-the-behaviour-of-combined-tags-search-changed) and [its linked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/393969?sort=newest)

Comment: [This answer over on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367270) attributes this behavior to there being no websocket for listening to the intersection of two tags... but this could be fixed (presumably rather easily) by just filtering out incoming posts that don't meet the search parameters on the client-side. Definitely an annoying bug.

Comment: @AndrewT. It isn't clear in the other question that the problem results from *new* questions being inserted into the search; but based on an examination of the provided evidence, it seems like that must be what is actually going on. So I guess this is in fact a duplicate.