# Recent fix broke AND-OR queries; cf "nn questions with new activity"

Tags: discussion, bug, tags, search

*This is not a dup of [Is multi tag search broken?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342814/is-multi-tag-search-broken) from 3 years ago!*  Search was working fine for me until about Feb 16 or 17, 2020; then it broke.  The new breakage may be related to that old Q&A.  One could argue that it is now "half broken".

When the page sits there for a while, it will say "24 questions with new activity".  If I click on *that* message, I get 24 semi-relevant questions -- perhaps all the ANDs in my Search were turned into OR.  If, instead, I *refresh* the page, it correctly performs the Search and may come up with a few new questions, not the 24.

I have long search queries like

`[mysql] [regex] or [mysql] [database-design] or [mysql] [latitude-longitude] or [mysql] [pivot-table] or [mysql] [sqldatatypes] or [mysql] [decimal]`

Until a couple of days ago, that query worked fine.  But now it sees that it turned into entirely OR.  Or manybe the [mysql] tags got lost.  Whatever...  It now claims that I have hundreds of new questions matching the search.  But it lies.

(Of course, I would like to say `[mysql] and ( ... or ... )`, but that does not seem to be possible.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is multi tag search broken?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342814/is-multi-tag-search-broken) ([meta-tag:status-bydesign]) — _“There’s some history here around whether pages specifying multiple tags should work as unions or intersections (by default). It isn’t consistent […]. However, if you’re explicit, it’ll always work as you expect”_ (from [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342829/4642212)), so do `[mysql] and [regex] or [mysql] and [database-design] or …`.

Comment: @user4642212 - Without parentheses, it is hard to be fully explicit.  Too many programmers fail to know the precedence between AND and OR.

Comment: _“This is not a dup of Is multi tag search broken? from 3 years ago!”_ — It should still be the same as [Has the behaviour of combined tags search changed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393969/4642212) which was closed as a dupe of that. This question is more likely to be a dupe of the recent one, but then none of the newer questions should be closed as a dupe of that 3-year-old one.

Comment: @yivi -- That is a dup, but it is not [yet] Answered.  I helped get it reopened.  Now that it is reopened, his could be made a dup of mine or vise versa.  In our opinion, which states the problem more clearly?

Comment: @yivi - Fine.  I accept that.  (But I would quibble with the wording since it talks about "Answered".)  With 11 upvotes betweens us, I hope the programmers take action soon.