# New questions notification ignores tags in search box

Tags: bug

In search textbox I specify tags `[midi] [c#]`, hit Enter, all is OK, all listed questions have both tags:

[image]

Waiting some time and I see that new questions appeared:

[image]

But when I expand new questions block, I see that these questions don't have `midi` tag:

[image]

When I press Enter again in the search textbox I see only `midi`+`c#` questions again.

So obviously something wrong:

- if `[midi] [c#]` means `midi` OR `c#`, I should see questions with either `midi` or `c#` when hit Enter in search box
- if `[midi] [c#]` means `midi` AND `c#`, I should see new questions only with both tags

Looks like a bug of new questions notification.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, but the problem the same. Can info be passed to developers of Stack Exchange?

Comment: _“It doesn't answer my question”_ — _Sigh_, of course… Stack Exchange should really [change the default comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339563/289905), especially [for Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340009/289905). _“Can info be passed to developers of Stack Exchange?”_ — What do you mean? A report on Meta already does this.

Comment: Yes, report on Meta does this, but seeing several threads about the same problem it looks like SE developers missed the problem.

Comment: Following a few links, there’s [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342829/4642212) stating that tag search without an explicit `and` or `or` keyword doesn’t behave consistently, so it’s always better to include these keywords explicitly. The devs appear to be aware of this, but I’m not sure they have a plan of how to fix this. Alternatively, you can create a question filter.

Comment: JPEG images? Aren't PNG images possible?

Comment: @PeterMortensen What images? Images in my question inserted by built-in Imgur widget and from what I see, images are in PNG format.