# Search by tags - different behavior for search and new activity (live-refresh)

Tags: bug, tag-search, live-refresh

I saw weird behavior - when I search for question by tags I gets only questions who has both of the tags (AND operator by default which makes sense).

However, if I keep the page open, and after sometime I get "One question with new activity" the question **can** contain only one of the tag and not both (as when the update is dynamically without refresh the page is using OR operator)

This is the page after I clicked the `"One question with new activity"`:
[image]
As you can see, this question has only `PHP` tag. After I refresh the page, this question disappear from the question's list.

I pretty sure that wasn't the behavior in the past - probably it was changed in the last year.

Is this the expected behavior? I think we should use the AND operator in the live-refresh as well.

Comment: Related: [Is multi tag search broken?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342814/4642212) and its linked questions.

Comment: Specifically, it looks, like it’s a duplicate of [Has the behaviour of combined tags search changed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393969/4642212).