# Searching [yaml][python] behaves differently from searching [python][yaml]

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

When I set my search to the tags

```
[python] [yaml]
```

the page will only update occasionally in the form of a bar

> X questions with new activity

and when you click on that bar you see questions that have the `[yaml]` tag, but not necessarily the `[python]` tag.

When I reverse the tag order:

```
[yaml] [python]
```

I get these updates much more frequently, for all question that have the `[python]` tag (but not necessarily the `[yaml]` tag.

Independent of tag order, if I refresh, any new questions that don't have **both tags** disappear.

Is only the last tag in the search "used" for these update messages (or always the second)? But more importantly can all tags, previously searched for, be used in determining what gets pushed to the open search page?

Comment: Perhaps this will help? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323525 or this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342814